# Realm Browser not showing Int column data

Tags: realm

I am just starting with Realm and have installed Realm Browser.
Realm is working in my project, allowing me to retrieve all data, but in the browser, I see no data in my two Int columns.[image: screen snap]

Answer (score 1):

The answer is to widen the columns!

I had exactly this problem but found that by default numeric columns are too narrow. Move the mouse pointer up to where the text "age" or "legs" is and it turns into the "column resize indicator" and then you can resize the columns.

There are suggestions that a) This may only be an issue on El Capitan and b) Realm released a new Browser today which may fix this issue.